# List multiple items through Paypal Express checkout using Omnipay & Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, payment-gateway, omnipay

Is it possible to list all products in a sites "cart" on PayPal. I ask because PayPal says "descriptions" instead of description and it would be nicer than having a combined total with a unhelpful description of "your basket"

```
$request = $gateway->purchase([
            'amount' => '150.00',
            'currency' => 'GBP',
            'description' => 'Your basket',
            'returnUrl' => 'http://localhost:8080/checkout/success',
            'cancelUrl' => 'http://localhost:8080/checkout/cancel'
        ])->send();
```

The documentation is vague or I may have overlooked the possibility but I've tried:

```
 $request = $gateway->purchase([
                'amount' => array('100','200'),
                'currency' => 'GBP',
                'description' => array('prod1','prod2'),
                'returnUrl' => 'http://localhost:8080/checkout/success',
                'cancelUrl' => 'http://localhost:8080/checkout/cancel'
            ])->send();
```

& 
 `$request = $gateway->purchase([data],[data])->send();` 
where data follows the above layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [omnipay array of products](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068618/omnipay-array-of-products)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this [post on Github](https://github.com/omnipay/omnipay/pull/154) which explains how this is achievable.

`setItems` function was added so that an array of items can be passed like so:

```
$request = $gateway->purchase([
            'amount'=>'70.00',
            'returnUrl' => 'http://localhost:8080/checkout/success',
            'cancelUrl' => 'http://localhost:8080/checkout/cancel'
        ])->setItems(array(
            array('name' => 'item1', 'quantity' => 2, 'price' => '10.00'),
            array('name' => 'item2', 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => '50.00')
        ))->send();
```

**Something to note**
The request will fail if the purchase amount does not equal the sum of the array of items.

Answer (score 0):

```
$gateway = Omnipay\Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
$gateway->setUsername('....');
$gateway->setPassword('....');
$gateway->setSignature('.....');
$items = new Omnipay\Common\ItemBag();

$items->add(array(
            'name' => 'prova',
            'quantity' => '1',
            'price' => 40.00,
));
$items->add(array(
            'name' => 'prova 2',
            'quantity' => '1',
            'price' => 10.00,
));
$response = $gateway->purchase(
            array(
                'cancelUrl'=>'http://.../pay/',
                'returnUrl'=>'http://.../pay/return_to_site',
                'amount' =>  50.00,
                'currency' => 'EUR'
            )
)->setItems($items)->send();
$response->redirect();
```